# Writing data to Elasticsearch:EsHadoopSerializationException

Tags: elasticsearch-hadoop

I am using ELasticsearch 5.4 and Hadoop 2.7.3 and wanna writing data from HDFS to Elasticsearch.My data in blog.json:

```
{"id":"1","title":"git简介","posttime":"2016-06-11","content":"svn与git的最主要区别..."}
{"id":"2","title":"ava中泛型的介绍与简单使用","posttime":"2016-06-12","content":"基本操作：CRUD ..."}
{"id":"3","title":"SQL基本操作","posttime":"2016-06-13","content":"svn与git的最主要区别..."}
{"id":"4","title":"Hibernate框架基础","posttime":"2016-06-14","content":"Hibernate框架基础..."}
{"id":"5","title":"Shell基本知识","posttime":"2016-06-15","content":"Shell是什么..."}
```

I put blog.json to HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -put blog.json /work
```

and then I start Elasticsearch 5.4 and write my java code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by bee on 4/1/17.
 */
public class HdfsToES {

    public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable,
            BytesWritable> {

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Mapper<Object, Text,
                NullWritable, BytesWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            byte[] line = value.toString().trim().getBytes();
            BytesWritable blog = new BytesWritable(line);
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), blog);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.setBoolean("mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution", false);
        conf.setBoolean("mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution", false);
        conf.set("es.nodes", "localhost:9200/");
        conf.set("es.resource", "blog/csdn");
        conf.set("es.mapping.id", "id");
        conf.set("es.input.json", "yes");

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "hadoop es write test");
        job.setMapperClass(HdfsToES.MyMapper.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(EsOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);

        // 设置输入路径
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path
                ("hdfs://localhost:9000//work/blog.json"));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

I got an empty index without any data in Elasticsearch the flowing exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.EsHadoopSerializationException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('b' (code 98)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@5cdff749; line: 1, column: 3]
```

It works in Elasticsearch 2.3 bu not 5.4.How to update my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable,
        BytesWritable> {

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Mapper<Object, Text,
            NullWritable, BytesWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        byte[] line = value.toString().trim().getBytes();
        BytesWritable blog = new BytesWritable(line);
        context.write(NullWritable.get(), blog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class someMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable, Text>
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Don't use `byteswritable` for `mapvalue`, just use `text`. It works on my elasticsearch6.1.1, hadoop 2.7.3